# API for raw Bitcoin latest block data?

Tags: api, raw-data

I would like to get the full raw data on the latest bitcoin block. I was hoping I could get this from an API.

I looked at [blockchain.com's](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api) API's but these don't seem to provide the full data for each block including the header and transactions.

Does anyone know of a good source for this? Or should I be looking at alternatives to an API?

Comment: I am not aware of any public endpoint that will serve you the raw bitcoin core data. You can try with other explorers like blockstream.info but if you're looking for raw data, the best option is to run your own bitcoin core node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony. I don't know if 'raw' is the correct terminology for me to use. I need the full block data so I can see the header and transactions. If that makes any difference?

Comment: So basically something like this? https://api.smartbit.com.au/v1/blockchain/block/360973

Comment: Thanks m1xolyd1an, yes perfect! Except is their a way to get this for the latest block?